# PHP Sendmail Arguments Linux

Tags: php, linux, xampp, sendmail, lampp

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

I know the -t argument tells Apache that email can be sent through php.

What does the -i argument do? And are there any more arguments worth knowing about?

One other I know of is -f myemail@example.com which is a sendmail from override.

Comment: find a command line and type `man sendmail`

Comment: I don't think the arguments in the php.ini file are for sendmail. If you look in the sendmail manual there is no -f option and -t option has nothing related to the php.ini file or Apache yet without -t sendmail() will not work. Plus like a lot of installs now, my sendmail symlinks to an MTA (such as Exim4).

Comment: I see the -f option now it expects the from email address without a space example: -fmyemail@example.com this manual is much clearer. http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendmail

Answer (score 0):

```
   -i        This  option,  which  has  the  same  effect  as  -oi, specifies that a dot on a line by itself should not terminate an incoming,
             non-SMTP message. I can find no documentation for this option in Solaris 2.4 Sendmail, but the mailx command in Solaris 2.4  uses
             it. See also -ti.
```

Answer (score 0):

*Here`s a Complete Guide list of commands if you wanna go deep through sendmail commands.*

[COMPLETE LIST OF UNIX System Manager's Manual(SENDMAIL)](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html)

**As for your question : **

```
 -i          Ignore dots alone on lines by themselves in incoming mes-
                 sages.  This should be set if you are reading data from a
                 file.
```

Simple sample sending of mail

```
    **<input>**
    # /usr/lib/sendmail -t - F 'Webmaster' -f 'webmaster@email.com'

    **<output**
    From: webmaster@email.com
    To: user@someemail.com
    Subject: Feedback Form 
    Hello World !
```

Comment: I don't think the arguments in the php.ini file are for sendmail.
If you look in the sendmail manual there is no -f option and -t option has nothing related to the php.ini file and Apache yet without -t sendmail() will not work. Plus like a lot of installs now, my sendmail symlinks to an MTA (such as Exim4).

Comment: I see the -f option now it expects the from email address without a space example: -fmyemail@example.com this manual is much clearer. http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sendmail